# Unconfirmed transaction for nearly 3 months

Tags: transactions

Sorry but I am fairly new to this. I have qt wallet and have done quite a few transactions, but around Xmas time I placed a few payments that didn't go through. After  checking the web, many said just to wait and the coins will come back. But as it's now been 3 months, is there anything else I can do? Please be basic as I'm not that experienced.

Comment: Do you have the transactions to show trough blockchain?
Which website did you send the payments to?
Were the transactions confirmed , how many confirms? Your question is a little vague can you please be a little more specific

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need to do is find the transaction i.d. 
There you will see everything if there is no confirmations after 3 months its just well strange , I think you can look for more answers also in bitcoin forums there are alot of people that can help there nad they answer usually instantly

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I just checked the bitcoin chain and found that the transaction id isn't there and the address the coins were sent to doesn't show and transactions at all (it was a new account set up for this one transaction). But my wallet still shows it as an outgoing transaction with 0/6 confirmations 23/12/15. Obviously its something wrong with my wallet, but I can't find any simple way to reset it. Do you have any ideas? And thank you either way for the help you have given so far, I really appreciate you taking the time to assist a complete stranger.